# Summation of data | Sigma notation

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am confused by two exercises from a textbook.

According to the solution, both exercises can be solved by using the following equation for a discrete Fourier transform

$y_j = y(t_j) = a_0 + \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k\cos\left(\frac{2\pi jk}{N}\right) + \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k\sin\left(\frac{2\pi jk}{N}\right)$

with

$a_m = \dfrac{2}{N} \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}y_j\cos\left(\frac{2\pi jm}{N}\right)$

and

$b_m = \dfrac{2}{N} \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}y_j\sin\left(\frac{2\pi jm}{N}\right)$

[See both exercises attached for more details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHi5W.png)

Now my question: To derive $a_m$ and $b_m$ in exercise 18 they use $\sum_{j=1}^{N}$ instead of $\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}$. In exercise 19 they use the equation as indicated above. I can't see why there should be a difference between the two exercises. Is it because of the nature of the two data sets (one starting at $y=0$, the other at $y>0$)? Am I missing some theory/notation rules? Thanks for your help.

Edit: Is it due to the property of the first data set that data points are equally spaced? This would allow using

$a_m = \dfrac{2}{N} \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{N}y_j\cos\left(\frac{2\pi jm}{N}\right)$

and

$b_m = \dfrac{2}{N} \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{N}y_j\sin\left(\frac{2\pi jm}{N}\right)$